# To to create a simple automated macro spell check?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to create an automated macro spell check in word using Visual Basic under the Developer tab. I am aware the coding that is place behind a macro button for regular spell check is

```
Sub SpellC()  
'  
' Macro3 Macro  
'  
'  
    If Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = True Then
        ActiveDocument.CheckGrammar  
    Else  
        ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling  
    End If  
End Sub
```

But my question is, how do I modify this to run when I close MS Word and open the document as well. If possible as well, how do I modify this to execute as soon as I type an incorrect word, to show me the list of word options that MS Word provides, when something is spelt wrong. Please don't discourage, I'm just trying to learn here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open VBA Editor
- Go to Project Explorer
- Double-click ThisDocument
- Select Document , Open from Objects & Events dropdown for creating sub for opening the document
- Same way for Document Close event

Refer this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-automatically-execute-a-word-macro-when-you-create-open-or-close-a-document/) for more details

It should look like this:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Call SpellC()
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()
    Call SpellC()
End Sub
```